# JavaScript video trailer (including YouTube iframe) playback issue with hoover on flip cards' front side

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, iframe

```
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" 
  href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
</head>

<main>
  <h1>TM</h1>
  <p>Game cards.</p>
  <p><a href="https://github.com/murattasci06"><i class="fab fa-github"></i></a></p>
</main>
<ul>
  <li class="card" onmouseenter="showTrailer('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rt-2cxAiPJk')">
    <div class="card__flipper">
      <div class="card__front">
        <img src="https://gecbunlari.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/Spiderman-No-Way-Home.jpg" alt="Spiderman">
        <p class="card__name"><span>Marvels</span><br>Spiderman</p>
        <p class="card__num">1</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card__back">
        <svg height="180" width="180">
          <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="55" stroke="#514d9b" stroke-width="35"  />
        </svg>
        <span>113.2</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
 
  <li class="card">
    <div class="card__flipper">
       <div class="card__front">
         <p class="card__name"><span>Aaron</span><br>Rodgers</p>
        <p class="card__num">12</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card__back">
        <svg height="180" width="180">
          <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="55" stroke="#35a541" stroke-width="35"  />
        </svg>
        <span>112.2</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <div class="card__flipper">
       <div class="card__front">
        <p class="card__name"><span>Ben</span><br>Roethlisberger</p>
        <p class="card__num">7</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card__back">
        <svg height="180" width="180">
          <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="55" stroke="#bdb235" stroke-width="35"  />
        </svg>
        <span>103.3</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <div class="card__flipper">
       <div class="card__front">
        <p class="card__name"><span>Peyton</span><br>Manning</p>
        <p class="card__num">18</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card__back">
        <svg height="180" width="180">
          <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="55" stroke="#db6623" stroke-width="35"  />
        </svg>
        <span>101.5</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <div class="card__flipper">
       <div class="card__front">
        <p class="card__name"><span>Tom</span><br>Brady</p>
        <p class="card__num">Eric</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card__back">
        <svg height="180" width="180">
          <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="55" stroke="#3e5eb3" stroke-width="35"  />
        </svg>
        <span>97.4</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <div class="card__flipper">
       <div class="card__front">
        <p class="card__name"><span>Drew</span><br>Brees</p>
        <p class="card__num">9</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card__back">
        <svg height="180" width="180">
          <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="55" stroke="#aa9e5c" stroke-width="35"  />
        </svg>
        <span>97.0</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>

<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  background: #1f1f1f;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Lato";
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  max-width: 800px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.card {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: calc(33.33% - 30px + 9.999px);
  height: 340px;
  margin: 0 30px 30px 0;
  perspective: 1000;
}
.card:first-child .card__front {
  background:#5271C2;
}

.card__front img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.card:first-child .card__num {
  text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(52, 78, 147, 0.8) , 2px 2px rgba(52, 79, 148, 0.802) , 3px 3px rgba(53, 79, 148, 0.804) , 4px 4px rgba(53, 80, 149, 0.806) , 5px 5px rgba(54, 80, 150, 0.808) , 6px 6px rgba(54, 81, 150, 0.81) , 7px 7px rgba(55, 81, 151, 0.812) , 8px 8px rgba(55, 82, 152, 0.814) , 9px 9px rgba(55, 82, 152, 0.816) , 10px 10px rgba(56, 83, 153, 0.818) , 11px 11px rgba(56, 83, 154, 0.82) , 12px 12px rgba(57, 83, 154, 0.822) , 13px 13px rgba(57, 84, 155, 0.824) , 14px 14px rgba(57, 84, 156, 0.826) , 15px 15px rgba(58, 85, 156, 0.828) , 16px 16px rgba(58, 85, 157, 0.83) , 17px 17px rgba(59, 86, 157, 0.832) , 18px 18px rgba(59, 86, 158, 0.834) , 19px 19px rgba(59, 87, 159, 0.836) , 20px 20px rgba(60, 87, 159, 0.838) , 21px 21px rgba(60, 88, 160, 0.84) , 22px 22px rgba(61, 88, 160, 0.842) , 23px 23px rgba(61, 88, 161, 0.844) , 24px 24px rgba(61, 89, 162, 0.846) , 25px 25px rgba(62, 89, 162, 0.848) , 26px 26px rgba(62, 90, 163, 0.85) , 27px 27px rgba(62, 90, 163, 0.852) , 28px 28px rgba(63, 90, 164, 0.854) , 29px 29px rgba(63, 91, 164, 0.856) , 30px 30px rgba(63, 91, 165, 0.858) , 31px 31px rgba(64, 92, 165, 0.86) , 32px 32px rgba(64, 92, 166, 0.862) , 33px 33px rgba(64, 92, 166, 0.864) , 34px 34px rgba(65, 93, 167, 0.866) , 35px 35px rgba(65, 93, 167, 0.868) , 36px 36px rgba(65, 94, 168, 0.87) , 37px 37px rgba(66, 94, 169, 0.872) , 38px 38px rgba(66, 94, 169, 0.874) , 39px 39px rgba(66, 95, 170, 0.876) , 40px 40px rgba(67, 95, 170, 0.878) , 41px 41px rgba(67, 96, 171, 0.88) , 42px 42px rgba(67, 96, 171, 0.882) , 43px 43px rgba(68, 96, 171, 0.884) , 44px 44px rgba(68, 97, 172, 0.886) , 45px 45px rgba(68, 97, 172, 0.888) , 46px 46px rgba(69, 97, 173, 0.89) , 47px 47px rgba(69, 98, 173, 0.892) , 48px 48px rgba(69, 98, 174, 0.894) , 49px 49px rgba(69, 98, 174, 0.896) , 50px 50px rgba(70, 99, 175, 0.898) , 51px 51px rgba(70, 99, 175, 0.9) , 52px 52px rgba(70, 99, 176, 0.902) , 53px 53px rgba(71, 100, 176, 0.904) , 54px 54px rgba(71, 100, 177, 0.906) , 55px 55px rgba(71, 100, 177, 0.908) , 56px 56px rgba(71, 101, 177, 0.91) , 57px 57px rgba(72, 101, 178, 0.912) , 58px 58px rgba(72, 101, 178, 0.914) , 59px 59px rgba(72, 102, 179, 0.916) , 60px 60px rgba(73, 102, 179, 0.918) , 61px 61px rgba(73, 102, 180, 0.92) , 62px 62px rgba(73, 103, 180, 0.922) , 63px 63px rgba(73, 103, 180, 0.924) , 64px 64px rgba(74, 103, 181, 0.926) , 65px 65px rgba(74, 103, 181, 0.928) , 66px 66px rgba(74, 104, 182, 0.93) , 67px 67px rgba(74, 104, 182, 0.932) , 68px 68px rgba(75, 104, 182, 0.934) , 69px 69px rgba(75, 105, 183, 0.936) , 70px 70px rgba(75, 105, 183, 0.938) , 71px 71px rgba(75, 105, 184, 0.94) , 72px 72px rgba(76, 106, 184, 0.942) , 73px 73px rgba(76, 106, 184, 0.944) , 74px 74px rgba(76, 106, 185, 0.946) , 75px 75px rgba(76, 106, 185, 0.948) , 76px 76px rgba(77, 107, 185, 0.95) , 77px 77px rgba(77, 107, 186, 0.952) , 78px 78px rgba(77, 107, 186, 0.954) , 79px 79px rgba(77, 107, 187, 0.956) , 80px 80px rgba(77, 108, 187, 0.958) , 81px 81px rgba(78, 108, 187, 0.96) , 82px 82px rgba(78, 108, 188, 0.962) , 83px 83px rgba(78, 109, 188, 0.964) , 84px 84px rgba(78, 109, 188, 0.966) , 85px 85px rgba(79, 109, 189, 0.968) , 86px 86px rgba(79, 109, 189, 0.97) , 87px 87px rgba(79, 110, 189, 0.972) , 88px 88px rgba(79, 110, 190, 0.974) , 89px 89px rgba(80, 110, 190, 0.976) , 90px 90px rgba(80, 110, 190, 0.978) , 91px 91px rgba(80, 111, 191, 0.98) , 92px 92px rgba(80, 111, 191, 0.982) , 93px 93px rgba(80, 111, 191, 0.984) , 94px 94px rgba(81, 111, 192, 0.986) , 95px 95px rgba(81, 112, 192, 0.988) , 96px 96px rgba(81, 112, 192, 0.99) , 97px 97px rgba(81, 112, 193, 0.992) , 98px 98px rgba(81, 112, 193, 0.994) , 99px 99px rgba(82, 113, 193, 0.996) , 100px 100px rgba(82, 113, 194, 0.998);
}
.card:nth-child(2) .card__front {
  background:#35a541;
}
.card:nth-child(2) .card__num {
  text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(34, 107, 42, 0.8) , 2px 2px rgba(34, 108, 42, 0.802) , 3px 3px rgba(35, 109, 43, 0.804) , 4px 4px rgba(35, 110, 43, 0.806) , 5px 5px rgba(35, 110, 43, 0.808) , 6px 6px rgba(35, 111, 44, 0.81) , 7px 7px rgba(36, 112, 44, 0.812) , 8px 8px rgba(36, 113, 44, 0.814) , 9px 9px rgba(36, 114, 45, 0.816) , 10px 10px rgba(36, 114, 45, 0.818) , 11px 11px rgba(37, 115, 45, 0.82) , 12px 12px rgba(37, 116, 46, 0.822) , 13px 13px rgba(37, 117, 46, 0.824) , 14px 14px rgba(37, 118, 46, 0.826) , 15px 15px rgba(38, 118, 47, 0.828) , 16px 16px rgba(38, 119, 47, 0.83) , 17px 17px rgba(38, 120, 47, 0.832) , 18px 18px rgba(38, 121, 47, 0.834) , 19px 19px rgba(39, 121, 48, 0.836) , 20px 20px rgba(39, 122, 48, 0.838) , 21px 21px rgba(39, 123, 48, 0.84) , 22px 22px rgba(39, 124, 49, 0.842) , 23px 23px rgba(40, 124, 49, 0.844) , 24px 24px rgba(40, 125, 49, 0.846) , 25px 25px rgba(40, 126, 49, 0.848) , 26px 26px rgba(40, 126, 50, 0.85) , 27px 27px rgba(41, 127, 50, 0.852) , 28px 28px rgba(41, 128, 50, 0.854) , 29px 29px rgba(41, 128, 50, 0.856) , 30px 30px rgba(41, 129, 51, 0.858) , 31px 31px rgba(41, 130, 51, 0.86) , 32px 32px rgba(42, 130, 51, 0.862) , 33px 33px rgba(42, 131, 52, 0.864) , 34px 34px rgba(42, 132, 52, 0.866) , 35px 35px rgba(42, 132, 52, 0.868) , 36px 36px rgba(42, 133, 52, 0.87) , 37px 37px rgba(43, 134, 53, 0.872) , 38px 38px rgba(43, 134, 53, 0.874) , 39px 39px rgba(43, 135, 53, 0.876) , 40px 40px rgba(43, 135, 53, 0.878) , 41px 41px rgba(44, 136, 54, 0.88) , 42px 42px rgba(44, 137, 54, 0.882) , 43px 43px rgba(44, 137, 54, 0.884) , 44px 44px rgba(44, 138, 54, 0.886) , 45px 45px rgba(44, 138, 54, 0.888) , 46px 46px rgba(44, 139, 55, 0.89) , 47px 47px rgba(45, 140, 55, 0.892) , 48px 48px rgba(45, 140, 55, 0.894) , 49px 49px rgba(45, 141, 55, 0.896) , 50px 50px rgba(45, 141, 56, 0.898) , 51px 51px rgba(45, 142, 56, 0.9) , 52px 52px rgba(46, 142, 56, 0.902) , 53px 53px rgba(46, 143, 56, 0.904) , 54px 54px rgba(46, 143, 56, 0.906) , 55px 55px rgba(46, 144, 57, 0.908) , 56px 56px rgba(46, 145, 57, 0.91) , 57px 57px rgba(46, 145, 57, 0.912) , 58px 58px rgba(47, 146, 57, 0.914) , 59px 59px rgba(47, 146, 58, 0.916) , 60px 60px rgba(47, 147, 58, 0.918) , 61px 61px rgba(47, 147, 58, 0.92) , 62px 62px rgba(47, 148, 58, 0.922) , 63px 63px rgba(47, 148, 58, 0.924) , 64px 64px rgba(48, 149, 59, 0.926) , 65px 65px rgba(48, 149, 59, 0.928) , 66px 66px rgba(48, 150, 59, 0.93) , 67px 67px rgba(48, 150, 59, 0.932) , 68px 68px rgba(48, 151, 59, 0.934) , 69px 69px rgba(48, 151, 60, 0.936) , 70px 70px rgba(49, 152, 60, 0.938) , 71px 71px rgba(49, 152, 60, 0.94) , 72px 72px rgba(49, 153, 60, 0.942) , 73px 73px rgba(49, 153, 60, 0.944) , 74px 74px rgba(49, 154, 60, 0.946) , 75px 75px rgba(49, 154, 61, 0.948) , 76px 76px rgba(50, 154, 61, 0.95) , 77px 77px rgba(50, 155, 61, 0.952) , 78px 78px rgba(50, 155, 61, 0.954) , 79px 79px rgba(50, 156, 61, 0.956) , 80px 80px rgba(50, 156, 62, 0.958) , 81px 81px rgba(50, 157, 62, 0.96) , 82px 82px rgba(50, 157, 62, 0.962) , 83px 83px rgba(51, 158, 62, 0.964) , 84px 84px rgba(51, 158, 62, 0.966) , 85px 85px rgba(51, 158, 62, 0.968) , 86px 86px rgba(51, 159, 63, 0.97) , 87px 87px rgba(51, 159, 63, 0.972) , 88px 88px rgba(51, 160, 63, 0.974) , 89px 89px rgba(51, 160, 63, 0.976) , 90px 90px rgba(52, 161, 63, 0.978) , 91px 91px rgba(52, 161, 63, 0.98) , 92px 92px rgba(52, 161, 64, 0.982) , 93px 93px rgba(52, 162, 64, 0.984) , 94px 94px rgba(52, 162, 64, 0.986) , 95px 95px rgba(52, 163, 64, 0.988) , 96px 96px rgba(52, 163, 64, 0.99) , 97px 97px rgba(52, 163, 64, 0.992) , 98px 98px rgba(53, 164, 65, 0.994) , 99px 99px rgba(53, 164, 65, 0.996) , 100px 100px rgba(53, 165, 65, 0.998);
}
.card:nth-child(3) {
  margin-right: 0;
}
.card:nth-child(3) .card__front {
  background: #bdb235;
}
.card:nth-child(3) .card__num {
  text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(129, 122, 36, 0.8) , 2px 2px rgba(130, 123, 36, 0.802) , 3px 3px rgba(131, 124, 37, 0.804) , 4px 4px rgba(132, 124, 37, 0.806) , 5px 5px rgba(133, 125, 37, 0.808) , 6px 6px rgba(133, 126, 37, 0.81) , 7px 7px rgba(134, 127, 37, 0.812) , 8px 8px rgba(135, 128, 38, 0.814) , 9px 9px rgba(136, 128, 38, 0.816) , 10px 10px rgba(137, 129, 38, 0.818) , 11px 11px rgba(138, 130, 38, 0.82) , 12px 12px rgba(138, 131, 39, 0.822) , 13px 13px rgba(139, 132, 39, 0.824) , 14px 14px rgba(140, 132, 39, 0.826) , 15px 15px rgba(141, 133, 39, 0.828) , 16px 16px rgba(142, 134, 40, 0.83) , 17px 17px rgba(142, 134, 40, 0.832) , 18px 18px rgba(143, 135, 40, 0.834) , 19px 19px rgba(144, 136, 40, 0.836) , 20px 20px rgba(145, 137, 40, 0.838) , 21px 21px rgba(145, 137, 41, 0.84) , 22px 22px rgba(146, 138, 41, 0.842) , 23px 23px rgba(147, 139, 41, 0.844) , 24px 24px rgba(148, 139, 41, 0.846) , 25px 25px rgba(148, 140, 41, 0.848) , 26px 26px rgba(149, 141, 42, 0.85) , 27px 27px rgba(150, 141, 42, 0.852) , 28px 28px rgba(150, 142, 42, 0.854) , 29px 29px rgba(151, 143, 42, 0.856) , 30px 30px rgba(152, 143, 42, 0.858) , 31px 31px rgba(152, 144, 43, 0.86) , 32px 32px rgba(153, 145, 43, 0.862) , 33px 33px rgba(154, 145, 43, 0.864) , 34px 34px rgba(154, 146, 43, 0.866) , 35px 35px rgba(155, 146, 43, 0.868) , 36px 36px rgba(156, 147, 44, 0.87) , 37px 37px rgba(156, 148, 44, 0.872) , 38px 38px rgba(157, 148, 44, 0.874) , 39px 39px rgba(158, 149, 44, 0.876) , 40px 40px rgba(158, 149, 44, 0.878) , 41px 41px rgba(159, 150, 45, 0.88) , 42px 42px rgba(160, 151, 45, 0.882) , 43px 43px rgba(160, 151, 45, 0.884) , 44px 44px rgba(161, 152, 45, 0.886) , 45px 45px rgba(161, 152, 45, 0.888) , 46px 46px rgba(162, 153, 45, 0.89) , 47px 47px rgba(163, 153, 46, 0.892) , 48px 48px rgba(163, 154, 46, 0.894) , 49px 49px rgba(164, 155, 46, 0.896) , 50px 50px rgba(164, 155, 46, 0.898) , 51px 51px rgba(165, 156, 46, 0.9) , 52px 52px rgba(166, 156, 46, 0.902) , 53px 53px rgba(166, 157, 47, 0.904) , 54px 54px rgba(167, 157, 47, 0.906) , 55px 55px rgba(167, 158, 47, 0.908) , 56px 56px rgba(168, 158, 47, 0.91) , 57px 57px rgba(168, 159, 47, 0.912) , 58px 58px rgba(169, 159, 47, 0.914) , 59px 59px rgba(169, 160, 47, 0.916) , 60px 60px rgba(170, 160, 48, 0.918) , 61px 61px rgba(171, 161, 48, 0.92) , 62px 62px rgba(171, 161, 48, 0.922) , 63px 63px rgba(172, 162, 48, 0.924) , 64px 64px rgba(172, 162, 48, 0.926) , 65px 65px rgba(173, 163, 48, 0.928) , 66px 66px rgba(173, 163, 49, 0.93) , 67px 67px rgba(174, 164, 49, 0.932) , 68px 68px rgba(174, 164, 49, 0.934) , 69px 69px rgba(175, 165, 49, 0.936) , 70px 70px rgba(175, 165, 49, 0.938) , 71px 71px rgba(176, 166, 49, 0.94) , 72px 72px rgba(176, 166, 49, 0.942) , 73px 73px rgba(177, 166, 50, 0.944) , 74px 74px rgba(177, 167, 50, 0.946) , 75px 75px rgba(178, 167, 50, 0.948) , 76px 76px rgba(178, 168, 50, 0.95) , 77px 77px rgba(179, 168, 50, 0.952) , 78px 78px rgba(179, 169, 50, 0.954) , 79px 79px rgba(180, 169, 50, 0.956) , 80px 80px rgba(180, 170, 50, 0.958) , 81px 81px rgba(180, 170, 51, 0.96) , 82px 82px rgba(181, 170, 51, 0.962) , 83px 83px rgba(181, 171, 51, 0.964) , 84px 84px rgba(182, 171, 51, 0.966) , 85px 85px rgba(182, 172, 51, 0.968) , 86px 86px rgba(183, 172, 51, 0.97) , 87px 87px rgba(183, 173, 51, 0.972) , 88px 88px rgba(184, 173, 51, 0.974) , 89px 89px rgba(184, 173, 52, 0.976) , 90px 90px rgba(184, 174, 52, 0.978) , 91px 91px rgba(185, 174, 52, 0.98) , 92px 92px rgba(185, 175, 52, 0.982) , 93px 93px rgba(186, 175, 52, 0.984) , 94px 94px rgba(186, 175, 52, 0.986) , 95px 95px rgba(187, 176, 52, 0.988) , 96px 96px rgba(187, 176, 52, 0.99) , 97px 97px rgba(187, 176, 53, 0.992) , 98px 98px rgba(188, 177, 53, 0.994) , 99px 99px rgba(188, 177, 53, 0.996) , 100px 100px rgba(189, 178, 53, 0.998);
}
.card:nth-child(4) .card__front {
  background: #db6623;
}
.card:nth-child(4) .card__num {
  text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(153, 71, 24, 0.8) , 2px 2px rgba(154, 71, 24, 0.802) , 3px 3px rgba(155, 72, 24, 0.804) , 4px 4px rgba(156, 72, 24, 0.806) , 5px 5px rgba(157, 73, 25, 0.808) , 6px 6px rgba(158, 73, 25, 0.81) , 7px 7px rgba(159, 74, 25, 0.812) , 8px 8px rgba(160, 74, 25, 0.814) , 9px 9px rgba(161, 75, 25, 0.816) , 10px 10px rgba(162, 75, 25, 0.818) , 11px 11px rgba(162, 75, 26, 0.82) , 12px 12px rgba(163, 76, 26, 0.822) , 13px 13px rgba(164, 76, 26, 0.824) , 14px 14px rgba(165, 77, 26, 0.826) , 15px 15px rgba(166, 77, 26, 0.828) , 16px 16px rgba(167, 77, 26, 0.83) , 17px 17px rgba(168, 78, 26, 0.832) , 18px 18px rgba(169, 78, 27, 0.834) , 19px 19px rgba(169, 79, 27, 0.836) , 20px 20px rgba(170, 79, 27, 0.838) , 21px 21px rgba(171, 79, 27, 0.84) , 22px 22px rgba(172, 80, 27, 0.842) , 23px 23px rgba(173, 80, 27, 0.844) , 24px 24px rgba(173, 81, 27, 0.846) , 25px 25px rgba(174, 81, 28, 0.848) , 26px 26px rgba(175, 81, 28, 0.85) , 27px 27px rgba(176, 82, 28, 0.852) , 28px 28px rgba(177, 82, 28, 0.854) , 29px 29px rgba(177, 82, 28, 0.856) , 30px 30px rgba(178, 83, 28, 0.858) , 31px 31px rgba(179, 83, 28, 0.86) , 32px 32px rgba(180, 83, 28, 0.862) , 33px 33px rgba(180, 84, 29, 0.864) , 34px 34px rgba(181, 84, 29, 0.866) , 35px 35px rgba(182, 85, 29, 0.868) , 36px 36px rgba(182, 85, 29, 0.87) , 37px 37px rgba(183, 85, 29, 0.872) , 38px 38px rgba(184, 86, 29, 0.874) , 39px 39px rgba(185, 86, 29, 0.876) , 40px 40px rgba(185, 86, 29, 0.878) , 41px 41px rgba(186, 87, 30, 0.88) , 42px 42px rgba(187, 87, 30, 0.882) , 43px 43px rgba(187, 87, 30, 0.884) , 44px 44px rgba(188, 87, 30, 0.886) , 45px 45px rgba(189, 88, 30, 0.888) , 46px 46px rgba(189, 88, 30, 0.89) , 47px 47px rgba(190, 88, 30, 0.892) , 48px 48px rgba(191, 89, 30, 0.894) , 49px 49px rgba(191, 89, 30, 0.896) , 50px 50px rgba(192, 89, 30, 0.898) , 51px 51px rgba(193, 90, 31, 0.9) , 52px 52px rgba(193, 90, 31, 0.902) , 53px 53px rgba(194, 90, 31, 0.904) , 54px 54px rgba(194, 90, 31, 0.906) , 55px 55px rgba(195, 91, 31, 0.908) , 56px 56px rgba(196, 91, 31, 0.91) , 57px 57px rgba(196, 91, 31, 0.912) , 58px 58px rgba(197, 92, 31, 0.914) , 59px 59px rgba(198, 92, 31, 0.916) , 60px 60px rgba(198, 92, 32, 0.918) , 61px 61px rgba(199, 92, 32, 0.92) , 62px 62px rgba(199, 93, 32, 0.922) , 63px 63px rgba(200, 93, 32, 0.924) , 64px 64px rgba(200, 93, 32, 0.926) , 65px 65px rgba(201, 94, 32, 0.928) , 66px 66px rgba(202, 94, 32, 0.93) , 67px 67px rgba(202, 94, 32, 0.932) , 68px 68px rgba(203, 94, 32, 0.934) , 69px 69px rgba(203, 95, 32, 0.936) , 70px 70px rgba(204, 95, 32, 0.938) , 71px 71px rgba(204, 95, 33, 0.94) , 72px 72px rgba(205, 95, 33, 0.942) , 73px 73px rgba(205, 96, 33, 0.944) , 74px 74px rgba(206, 96, 33, 0.946) , 75px 75px rgba(206, 96, 33, 0.948) , 76px 76px rgba(207, 96, 33, 0.95) , 77px 77px rgba(208, 97, 33, 0.952) , 78px 78px rgba(208, 97, 33, 0.954) , 79px 79px rgba(209, 97, 33, 0.956) , 80px 80px rgba(209, 97, 33, 0.958) , 81px 81px rgba(210, 98, 33, 0.96) , 82px 82px rgba(210, 98, 34, 0.962) , 83px 83px rgba(211, 98, 34, 0.964) , 84px 84px rgba(211, 98, 34, 0.966) , 85px 85px rgba(212, 99, 34, 0.968) , 86px 86px rgba(212, 99, 34, 0.97) , 87px 87px rgba(213, 99, 34, 0.972) , 88px 88px rgba(213, 99, 34, 0.974) , 89px 89px rgba(214, 99, 34, 0.976) , 90px 90px rgba(214, 100, 34, 0.978) , 91px 91px rgba(214, 100, 34, 0.98) , 92px 92px rgba(215, 100, 34, 0.982) , 93px 93px rgba(215, 100, 34, 0.984) , 94px 94px rgba(216, 101, 34, 0.986) , 95px 95px rgba(216, 101, 35, 0.988) , 96px 96px rgba(217, 101, 35, 0.99) , 97px 97px rgba(217, 101, 35, 0.992) , 98px 98px rgba(218, 101, 35, 0.994) , 99px 99px rgba(218, 102, 35, 0.996) , 100px 100px rgba(219, 102, 35, 0.998);
}
.card:nth-child(5) .card__front {
  background: #3e5eb3;
}
.card:nth-child(5) .card__num {
  text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(42, 64, 122, 0.8) , 2px 2px rgba(42, 64, 123, 0.802) , 3px 3px rgba(43, 65, 124, 0.804) , 4px 4px rgba(43, 65, 125, 0.806) , 5px 5px rgba(43, 66, 125, 0.808) , 6px 6px rgba(43, 66, 126, 0.81) , 7px 7px rgba(44, 67, 127, 0.812) , 8px 8px rgba(44, 67, 128, 0.814) , 9px 9px rgba(44, 67, 129, 0.816) , 10px 10px rgba(45, 68, 129, 0.818) , 11px 11px rgba(45, 68, 130, 0.82) , 12px 12px rgba(45, 69, 131, 0.822) , 13px 13px rgba(45, 69, 132, 0.824) , 14px 14px rgba(46, 69, 132, 0.826) , 15px 15px rgba(46, 70, 133, 0.828) , 16px 16px rgba(46, 70, 134, 0.83) , 17px 17px rgba(46, 71, 135, 0.832) , 18px 18px rgba(47, 71, 135, 0.834) , 19px 19px rgba(47, 71, 136, 0.836) , 20px 20px rgba(47, 72, 137, 0.838) , 21px 21px rgba(47, 72, 138, 0.84) , 22px 22px rgba(48, 73, 138, 0.842) , 23px 23px rgba(48, 73, 139, 0.844) , 24px 24px rgba(48, 73, 140, 0.846) , 25px 25px rgba(48, 74, 140, 0.848) , 26px 26px rgba(49, 74, 141, 0.85) , 27px 27px rgba(49, 74, 142, 0.852) , 28px 28px rgba(49, 75, 142, 0.854) , 29px 29px rgba(49, 75, 143, 0.856) , 30px 30px rgba(50, 75, 144, 0.858) , 31px 31px rgba(50, 76, 144, 0.86) , 32px 32px rgba(50, 76, 145, 0.862) , 33px 33px rgba(50, 76, 146, 0.864) , 34px 34px rgba(50, 77, 146, 0.866) , 35px 35px rgba(51, 77, 147, 0.868) , 36px 36px rgba(51, 77, 147, 0.87) , 37px 37px rgba(51, 78, 148, 0.872) , 38px 38px rgba(51, 78, 149, 0.874) , 39px 39px rgba(52, 78, 149, 0.876) , 40px 40px rgba(52, 79, 150, 0.878) , 41px 41px rgba(52, 79, 151, 0.88) , 42px 42px rgba(52, 79, 151, 0.882) , 43px 43px rgba(52, 80, 152, 0.884) , 44px 44px rgba(53, 80, 152, 0.886) , 45px 45px rgba(53, 80, 153, 0.888) , 46px 46px rgba(53, 81, 153, 0.89) , 47px 47px rgba(53, 81, 154, 0.892) , 48px 48px rgba(53, 81, 155, 0.894) , 49px 49px rgba(54, 81, 155, 0.896) , 50px 50px rgba(54, 82, 156, 0.898) , 51px 51px rgba(54, 82, 156, 0.9) , 52px 52px rgba(54, 82, 157, 0.902) , 53px 53px rgba(54, 83, 157, 0.904) , 54px 54px rgba(55, 83, 158, 0.906) , 55px 55px rgba(55, 83, 158, 0.908) , 56px 56px rgba(55, 83, 159, 0.91) , 57px 57px rgba(55, 84, 159, 0.912) , 58px 58px rgba(55, 84, 160, 0.914) , 59px 59px rgba(55, 84, 160, 0.916) , 60px 60px rgba(56, 85, 161, 0.918) , 61px 61px rgba(56, 85, 161, 0.92) , 62px 62px rgba(56, 85, 162, 0.922) , 63px 63px rgba(56, 85, 162, 0.924) , 64px 64px rgba(56, 86, 163, 0.926) , 65px 65px rgba(57, 86, 163, 0.928) , 66px 66px rgba(57, 86, 164, 0.93) , 67px 67px rgba(57, 86, 164, 0.932) , 68px 68px rgba(57, 87, 165, 0.934) , 69px 69px rgba(57, 87, 165, 0.936) , 70px 70px rgba(57, 87, 166, 0.938) , 71px 71px rgba(58, 87, 166, 0.94) , 72px 72px rgba(58, 88, 167, 0.942) , 73px 73px rgba(58, 88, 167, 0.944) , 74px 74px rgba(58, 88, 168, 0.946) , 75px 75px rgba(58, 88, 168, 0.948) , 76px 76px rgba(58, 89, 169, 0.95) , 77px 77px rgba(59, 89, 169, 0.952) , 78px 78px rgba(59, 89, 170, 0.954) , 79px 79px rgba(59, 89, 170, 0.956) , 80px 80px rgba(59, 89, 170, 0.958) , 81px 81px rgba(59, 90, 171, 0.96) , 82px 82px rgba(59, 90, 171, 0.962) , 83px 83px rgba(59, 90, 172, 0.964) , 84px 84px rgba(60, 90, 172, 0.966) , 85px 85px rgba(60, 91, 173, 0.968) , 86px 86px rgba(60, 91, 173, 0.97) , 87px 87px rgba(60, 91, 173, 0.972) , 88px 88px rgba(60, 91, 174, 0.974) , 89px 89px rgba(60, 92, 174, 0.976) , 90px 90px rgba(60, 92, 175, 0.978) , 91px 91px rgba(61, 92, 175, 0.98) , 92px 92px rgba(61, 92, 175, 0.982) , 93px 93px rgba(61, 92, 176, 0.984) , 94px 94px rgba(61, 93, 176, 0.986) , 95px 95px rgba(61, 93, 177, 0.988) , 96px 96px rgba(61, 93, 177, 0.99) , 97px 97px rgba(61, 93, 177, 0.992) , 98px 98px rgba(62, 93, 178, 0.994) , 99px 99px rgba(62, 94, 178, 0.996) , 100px 100px rgba(62, 94, 179, 0.998);
}
.card:nth-child(6) .card__front {
  background: #aa9e5c;
}
.card:nth-child(6) .card__num {
  text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(122, 113, 64, 0.8);
}
.card:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
.card__flipper {
  cursor: pointer;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
}
.card__front, .card__back {
  position: absolute;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 340px;
}
.card__front {
  transform: rotateY(0);
  z-index: 2;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.card__back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg) scale(1.1);
  background: #141414;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.card__back span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.card__name {
  font-size: 32px;
  line-height: 0.9;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.card__name span {
  font-size: 14px;
}
.card__num {
  font-size: 100px;
  margin: 0 8px 0 0;
  font-weight: 700;
}
@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .card__num {
    font-size: 70px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .card {
    width: 100%;
    height: 290px;
    margin-right: 0;
    float: none;
  }
  .card .card__front,
  .card .card__back {
    height: 290px;
  }
}

/* Demo */
main {
  text-align: center;
}
main h1, main p {
  margin: 0 0 12px 0;
}
main h1 {
  margin-top: 12px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.fa-github {
  color: white; 
  font-size: 30px;
}


</style>

<script>
var Flipper = (function() {
  var card = $('.card');
  var flipper = card.find('.card__flipper');
  var win = $(window);
  
  var flip = function() {
    var thisCard = $(this);
    var thisFlipper = thisCard.find('.card__flipper');
    var offset = thisCard.offset();
    var xc = win.width() / 2;
    var yc = win.height() / 2;
    var docScroll = $(document).scrollTop();
    var cardW = thisCard.outerWidth() / 2;
    var cardH = thisCard.height() / 2;

    var transX = xc - offset.left - cardW;
    var transY = docScroll + yc - offset.top - cardH;
//     if (offset.top > card.height()) transY = docScroll - offset.top + cardH;
    if (win.width() <= 700) transY = 0;
    
    if (card.hasClass('active')) unflip();
        
    thisCard.css({'z-index': '3'}).addClass('active');
    
    thisFlipper.css({
      'transform': 'translate3d(' + transX + 'px,' + transY + 'px, 0) rotateY(180deg) scale(1)',
      '-webkit-transform': 'translate3d(' + transX + 'px,' + transY + 'px, 0) rotateY(180deg) scale(1)',
      '-ms-transform': 'translate3d(' + transX + 'px,' + transY + 'px, 0) rotateY(180deg) scale(1)'
    }).addClass('active');
    
    return false;
  };
  
  var unflip = function(e) {
    card.css({'z-index': '1'}).removeClass('active');
    flipper.css({
      'transform': 'none',
      '-webkit-transform': 'none',
      '-ms-transform': 'none'
    }).removeClass('active');
  };
  
  var bindActions = function() {
    card.on('click', flip);
    win.on('click', unflip);
  }
  
  var init = function() {
    bindActions();
  };
  
  return {
    init: init
  };
  
}());
Flipper.init();  
</script>

<!-- HOOVER FOR TRAILER -->
<script>
let timeoutId;
  let isHovering = false;

  function showTrailer(videoUrl) {
    isHovering = true;
    timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
      if (isHovering) {
        let cardBack = document.querySelector(".card__back");
        cardBack.innerHTML = `
          <iframe width="180" height="180" src="${videoUrl}?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
          <span>113.2</span>
        `;
        cardBack.style.backgroundColor = "#514d9b";
        cardBack.style.transform = "rotateY(180deg)";
      }
    }, 4000);
  }

  function hideTrailer() {
    isHovering = false;
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);

    let cardBack = document.querySelector(".card__back");
    cardBack.innerHTML = `<span>113.2</span>`;
    cardBack.style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
    cardBack.style.transform = "rotateY(0)";
  }
</script>
```

Hello friends, I have 6 revolving cards that are opened when the left mouse button is clicked. For these six cards, I want to play the trailer of the movie when I wait 4 seconds with the mouse on the **front of the card automatically.(trailer frame's size:up to the size of the card)** **If the mouse is not on the card or when the trailer is over,** the front of the card (for instance spiderman visual)  will be shown again, but with the code I added **(HOOVER FOR TRAILER)** it is trying to do something on the back of the card and I didn't get what I wanted. How can I do what I want?

**Note: I haven't added the movie information and link of the other cards yet, but the update in the JavaScript code will be used for 6 cards as well. So it will be generic.**

**Explanations:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

### Version of Chrome: 115.0.5790.171

Comment: Movie trailer is a youtube iframe. This is not just a "video"!

Comment: do you want like this: https://jsfiddle.net/ahcwxs6n/  (video is not running properly because of iframe issue, it will work fine at you local system)

Comment: @Dr. Alive to die - Anant Thank you for your response. I just need a few changes based on the demo in the link:
**1)** I want the trailer to start with a delay of 4 seconds while the mouse is on the card. It starts right now. 

**2)** When the trailer is finished on the card, I want Marvels Spiderman 1 (blue background) image to appear again instead of the youtube frame.

Comment: **3)** When the code in the question works, the back of the card is visible when left-clicking the mouse on the card. (there are numbers on the back) I want **that part** of the original code to work the same way. So that part should not be broken in the code.

Comment: @Dr.Alivetodie-Anant I did that too: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1V24_H53lbW3FmrlJrLoj6OFpt2-j2RoL/view?usp=sharing
I have handled the delayed preview event, but the chrome browser is preventing the autoplay, I guess, after 1 time of manual play, autoplay can be activated from the 2nd try. Also, there is no full screen playback on the card. On the other hand, when the trailer ends, I cannot switch to the front of the card (https://gecbunlari.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/Spiderman-No-Way-Home.jpg)

Answer (score 4):

There are several problems with the code.

First, here's a [full working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/uq6g7rsm/). Now, here's how to fix the code:

1. If you'd look in the browser's dev tools console, you can see the error:

   > Refused to display 'https://www.youtube.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

   Meaning, YouTube blocks displaying content in an iframe.

   Instead, you should use the `/embed` path, so instead of:

   ```
   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rt-2cxAiPJk
   ```

   use:

   ```
   https://www.youtube.com/embed/rt-2cxAiPJk
   ```
2. The `onmouseenter` event handler - which is `showTrailer` - is being constantly called even when the mouse just moves a bit over the card, so the trailer is being constantly refreshed.

   To fix it, you should guard the code in `showTrailer` to only execute if the card is active and no iframe was already attached to it.

   So just add this:

   ```
   function showTrailer(event, videoUrl) {
      var $target = $(event.target);
      if (!$target.hasClass('active') ||
           $target.find('iframe').length) 
         return;
      //
      // ... rest of the code ...
      //
   }
   ```

   And pass the event to it:

   ```
   onmouseenter="showTrailer(event, ...)"
   ```
3. You'll need to remove the iframe once a click is made outside the card - otherwise, the trailer just keeps playing in the background.

   So inside `unflip`, add this final line:

   ```
   var unflip = function(e) {
      //
      // ... existing code ...
      //
      card.find('iframe').remove();
   }
   ```
4. Clicking outside the *visible* card to stop the trailer may occur on the *hidden* card element (which is hidden when the trailer displays - so the user may try to just click there) instead of clicking the wrapping window. This is undesired, which stops the trailer from running.

   To fix, just add this in `flip`:

   ```
   var flip = function() {
       var thisCard = $(this);
       if (thisCard.hasClass("active"))
           return;

       //
       // ... rest of the code ...
       // 
   }
   ```

Comment: The redundancy I put out about the backend in the question caused a visual misunderstanding :)  Actually, I didn't want any changes regarding the back of the card. That part works. The changes I want are only on the front of the card. I wanted the size of the trailer to appear in the full dimensions of the card and to play automatically when the mouse cursor is held on the front of the card for 4s. (without pressing the play button) I wanted the spiderman image to appear again when the video is finished or when the cursor is moved outside the card

Comment: @murattaşçı I am unable to see any video code in your html

Comment: You can see the YouTube link in the code:li class="card" onmouseenter="showTrailer('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rt-2cxAiPJk')"